# Laravel Named Group Routes

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to name a Group of Routes?

Something like:

```
Route::group(array('as'=>'fruits'), function(){
   Route::get('apple', array('as'=>'apple','uses'=>'fruits@apple'));
   Route::post('apple', array('uses'=>'fruits@editapple'));
   Route::get('pear', array('as'=>'pear', 'uses'=>'fruits@pear'));
});
```

Then check if the URL is "fruits" by doing:

```
if (Request::route()->is('fruits')){
   // One of the "fruits" routes is active
}
```

Or do I have to:

```
Route::get('fruits/apple', array('as'=>'apple','uses'=>'fruits@apple'));
Route::post('fruits/apple', array('uses'=>'fruits@editapple'));
Route::get('fruits/pear', array('as'=>'pear', 'uses'=>'fruits@pear'));
```

Then check by:

```
if(URI::is('fruits/*')){
   //"fruits" active
}
```

It's for a navmenu.

Answer (score 2):

Can't see if you are using Laravel 3 or Laravel 4. With Laravel 4 you can use [Route Prefixing](http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing#route-prefixing)

```php
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'fruits'), function()
{
    Route::get('apple', array('as'=>'apple','uses'=>'fruits@apple'));
    Route::post('apple', array('uses'=>'fruits@editapple'));
    Route::get('pear', array('as'=>'pear', 'uses'=>'fruits@pear'));
});
```

You can check it by using this

```php
if(Request::is('fruits/*')) {
    // One of the "fruits" routes is active
}
```

When you are using Laravel 3, I think you have to create an bundle named fruits so you have the url prefix.

Then you can check the active route by this way

```php
if(URI::is('fruits/*')){
   //"fruits" active
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm still new to laravel so will look through how to make a bundle.

Comment: Checkout the docs on http://laravel.com/docs/bundles#creating-bundles. If you're just stared with your application, its better to switch to Laravel 4. It's beta now, but they release it this month.

Comment: Ah yes, Resource Controllers is just what i was looking for. Next problem will be to switch to Laravel 4 :)

Comment: Try a tutorial like http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-uber-quick-start-with-auth-guide for a quick start ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't name a group using your first example but I think you can do it but in a different way (sharing my idea, don't know right or wrong) , tested only in `version 3`

**Routes.php**

```
Route::any('/fruits/(:any)', function($fruite){
   // Pass a parameter to the method, for example (demo purpose only)
   $param_for_method = $fruite == 'apple' ? 'Green' : 'Yellow';
   // Call the controller method, $fruite will represent (:any)
   Controller::call("fruits@$fruite", array($param_for_method));
});
```

**Your Controller :**

```
class Fruits_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
    public function action_apple($args)
    {
        //
    }

    public function action_banana($args)
    {
        //
    }

    // you can create as many fruit's method as you want
}
```

Now, if we write `http://yourdomain.dev/fruits/apple` then it'll call the `apple` method from our `fruits` controller and the parameter will be `Green` that is accessible using `$args` and if we write `http://yourdomain.dev/fruits/banana` then you know the rest.